# How to delete what's between two spaces or blanks using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, regex, shell-script, sed

I got this pattern:

```
ethernet-em1     016f2bbf-3268-4229-a25b-c7f94b6e52dc  802-3-ethernet  em1
virbr0           4fc0e260-b21a-4a9d-a74d-3ec9f124976f  bridge          virbr0
```

what i want is to get this one:

```
ethernet-em1    802-3-ethernet  em1
virbr0          bridge          virbr0
```

The regex that i'm looking for is to delete what's between two Blanks.

so how can i reach the previous result using "sed"?

Thanks.

Comment: A better tool to remove a _column_ from a text file is `awk`. _“delete what's between two Blanks”_ This would result in a simpler regex but would remove the 3rd column, too.

Comment: Thanks @Melebius for your comment, could you please provide me with the right awk command here, to achive the wanted result ?!, i need sometimes to delete the second and some times the third column and sometimes both thats why my question is a lil bit general. thanks again :D

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361632/delete-a-column-with-awk-or-sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you want to exclude is the UUID, you can just exclude it and the whitespace before:

```
sed 's/\s\s*[0-9a-f-]*//'
```

or even

```
sed 's/\s\s*[0-9a-f]*-[0-9a-f]*-[0-9a-f]*-[0-9a-f]*-[0-9a-f]*//'
```

Removing "everything between spaces" is done by

```
 sed 's/\(\s\s*\)[^\s][^\s]*\(\s\)/\1\2/'
```

but produces a different result: It will output

```
 ethernet-em1      em1
 virbr0            virbr0
```

as the 3rd word is also "between spaces"

Comment: Thanks alot @Eugen Rieck, your reg worked, but if you know some regex to delete what between two specific spaces occurrences, like between the first space occurrence and the second space occurrence . could you please help me with that.

Comment: @M.T This is not what you want: Removing "everything between whitespace" will let you end up with only `ethernet-em1      em1` (as `802-3-ethernet`is also between spaces)

Comment: i really thank you for your help, your answer is really useful, i actually wanted the both results but i didn't add that to the question "my bad". also i want it for educational reasons. thanks again @Eugen Rieck

Answer (score 1):

If you want specific answer using ***sed*** then answer given by [Eugen Rieck](https://superuser.com/users/300968/eugen-rieck) is perfect.

Another solution to the problems of selecting data on the basis of space as delimiter will be using ***awk*** :

```
awk -F' ' '{print $1" "$3" "$4}'
```

This will leave the 2nd column and print other three with space, as shown below :

```
ethernet-em1    802-3-ethernet  em1
virbr0          bridge          virbr0
```